# How do i get the Specflow scenario outline example data to a table

Tags: selenium, specflow

Is there any way to get the scenario context outline example values i mean all the values in to a table

```
Scenario Outline: Create a Matter

Given I enter  "< parameter1 >"
Then I enter "<parameter2>"
Then I enter "<parameter3>"
Then I enter "<parameter4>"
Then review all the parameters entered above in this final step

Examples:
| parameter1   | Paramter2|Parameter3|Parameter4|....|parameter14|
| value        |value2    |value3    |value4    |....|value14|
```

in the above scenario is there any way to get all the example values in step4 to a table
I know I can set ScenarioContext.Current[parameter1] = value in each step
In my case I have 14 parameters which are used in each step but in the final step i need to use all the 14 parameters
is  there any way I get the example values in to table.

I don't want to break in to smaller scenario
like below

```
Scenario: breaking in to smaller chunks    
Given I enter  the following
| parameter1   | Paramter2|
| value        |value2|
```

Comment: Could you post the Scenario as text? Then I can easily adjust it to that what I think you would like to have.

Comment: I have done @AndreasWillich

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I use that may help. Andreas is the expert though on this stuff and he probably has a better idea. Since your format was less than ideal, I used a basic scenario.

Change it to a "Scenario" and Drop the "Scenario Outline".

The feature looks like this:

```
Scenario: Validate Shipping Fees
When the user enters the State then we can verify the city and shipping fee

| City                      | State         | Shipping |
| Boulder                   | Colorado      | 6.00  |
| Houston                   | Texas         | 8.00  |
```

Add the Table.

```
public class ShippingTable
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Shipping { get; set; }

}
```

Then in your step:

```
     [When(@"the user enters the State then we can verify the city and shipping fee")]
    public void WhenTheUserEnterTheStateThenWeCanVerifyTheCityAndShippingFee(Table table)
    {

        var CityState = table.CreateSet<ShippingTable>();
        foreach (var row in CityState)
        {
             
            try
            {
                Pages.CheckoutPage.SelectState(row.State);
                Pages.CheckoutPage.SelectCity(row.City);
                var recdPrice = Pages.CheckoutPage.GetShippingPrice;
                Assert.AreEqual(row.shipping, recdPrice);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception("This is jacked up");
            }

         }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks@Dazed but i will have a table with 3 or 4 parameters in each step.. like in your example i will city state shipping in one scenario ...i have 4 to 5 scenarios in my case & in the final step i need the information from the all above 4 to 5 scenarios

Comment: @user4391664 You need in one step the parameters of all examples? You can only access the parameters of the current example.

Comment: Yes in the final step i need the parameters of all the example @AndreasWillich